# Factorizing the "rendered" attribute over several JSF elements

Tags: jsf

Given the following JSF fragment:

```
<h:outputText ... rendered="#{bean.r} />
<h:outputText ... rendered="#{bean.r} />
<h:outputText ... rendered="#{bean.r} />
```

How can I factorize to something that would look like:

```
<h:someKindOfGroupOrSomething rendered="#{bean.r}>
    <h:outputText ... />
    <h:outputText ... />
    <h:outputText ... />
</h:someKindOfGroupOrSomething>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a [PanelGroup](http://www.horstmann.com/corejsf/jsf-tags.html) - JSF 
If you use MyFaces Trinidad you can use [Group](http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/trinidad-api/tagdoc/tr_group.html)